# The program does not have the access rights specified in the manifest

Tags: java, android, permissions, gps, manifest

I study GPS. Day nothing worked. Examples from various sources. Until I checked the access rights. Even if they are spelled out in the manifest, they are not in the program. What's my mistake?

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWhSK5ZU5Pk&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: that means you didnt grant the permission for the app https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
    </uses-permission> I made a video on purpose. Because the manifest has the right to access the location definition.

Comment: That does not grant your app permission, you have to ask the user to explicitly grant the permission. Again please read the link I posted

Comment: I understand what you are talking about. Thanks. I'll figure it out now.